# Setting Subtotals to the bottom of an Excel table in VBA from MS Access

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have a simple MS Access Query the I put out to Excel.  I just want to add totals to the bottom outside the table, so that if the user filters the table, they can see the SUBTOTAL, so I'm using SUBTOTAL(109, [MyField]).

I've temporarily turned on the Excel object model, so I can see the intellisense because I keep getting errors when setting the range for determining the bottom of the table in Excel. Everything works fine except for the bottom.  I will turn off the Excel object model when it works.  I apologize that I forget the term for declaring 'as Object' instead of referring directly example:  xlApp as Excel.Application.

```
Public Sub ShowAllTotals()
    Dim xlApp As excel.Application ' Object
    Dim WB As excel.Workbook 'Object
    Dim xlSheet As excel.Worksheet ' Object
    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim strLocation As String
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim x, M, i As Integer
    Dim fld As Variant
    Dim rng As Object, TBL As Object, xlBottom As Object
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim iCols(3 To 10) As Integer
    Dim intRecords As Integer, intTotals As Integer, intCOL As Integer

    strSQL = "SELECT COB_ID, BL AS [COB TITLE], ANNUAL AS CONTROL, ALLOCATION, SP_C, SP_O, COMMITS, OBS, EXPN, OBS_SP_RATE, RA AS AVAILABLE " _
           & "FROM TOTALS_COB_ALL;"

    Debug.Print strSQL
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xlApp.Visible = False
    Set xlSheet = xlApp.Workbooks.Add().Sheets(1)
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
    With xlSheet.Rows("2:" & xlSheet.Rows.Count).Interior
        .Pattern = xlNone
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With

    With xlSheet.Rows("2:" & xlSheet.Rows.Count).Font
        .Name = "Calibri"
        .FontStyle = "Regular"
        .Size = 11
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMinor
    End With

    'PLACE
    intCOL = 1

    For Each fld In rs.Fields
        xlSheet.Cells(1, intCOL).Value = fld.Name
        intCOL = intCOL + 1
    Next

    With xlSheet
        .Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
        .Columns("C:I").NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"
        .Columns("J").NumberFormat = "0.00%"
        .Columns("K").NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"
        .Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With

    'Format the Table in Excel
    Set rng = xlSheet.Range(xlSheet.Range("A1"), xlSheet.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell))
    Set TBL = xlSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rng, , xlYes)
    TBL.TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium2"
    xlSheet.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

    'ADD TOTALS ATTEMPT

    intRecords = rs.RecordCount
    Dim strRange As String
    strRange = "C" & intRecords + 2
    Set xlBottom = xlSheet.Range(strRange)
    With xlSheet
        .Range("C79").Offset(0, 3).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUBTOTAL(109, [CONTROL])"
        'Range(xlBottom.Offset(0, 3).Address).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUBTOTAL(109,[CONTROL])" 'CONTROL
        '.Offset(0, 4).Address.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUBTOTAL(109,[ALLOCATION])" 'ALLOCATION
        '.Offset(0, 5).Address.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUBTOTAL(109,[SP_C])" 'SP_C
        '.Offset(0, 6).Address.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUBTOTAL(109,[SP_O])" 'SP_O
        '.Offset(0, 7).Address.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUBTOTAL(109,[COMMITS])" 'COMMITS
        '.Offset(0, 8).Address.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUBTOTAL(109,[OBS])" 'OBS
        '.Offset(0, 9).Address.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUBTOTAL(109,[EXPN])" 'EXPN
        '.Offset(0, 11).Address.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUBTOTAL(109,[AVAILABLE])" 'AVAILABLE
    End With

    'cleanup
    Set xlSheet = Nothing
    xlApp.Visible = True
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set rng = Nothing
    Set TBL = Nothing
    Set xlBottom = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I also cleaned up your code. It still needs work but now more readable. Also hungarian notation is the aids of variable naming conventions.

Comment: I am open to learning better variable notation. Thank you. What are your suggestions?

Comment: Be consistent and name things describing what theyre used for. strSQL is dumb IMO - its pointless to say its a string b/c its already contextually implied that its a string. Most of the time it just confuses readability not to mention its akin to saying something like tuna-fish. Tuna is a fish why are we double word talking? Another example - intRecords. Why? On every occurrence in your code its painfully obvious what data type it is w/o having to say so.

Comment: Got it.  strSQL and intRecords have often been something I use as dummy template constructors when I want to quickly see if something will work.  Also note how strSQL makes me quickly remember Set rs = CurrentDB.OpenRecordset(strSQL) without having to think about it too much.  Your reaction is expected if I don’t spend an additional 5 min cleaning up code prior to posting.  By the same token, if at any moment my code is ready to post, that would even be better, so thanks for calling me out on the Tuna Fish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a neat piece of code I just grabbed from an annoying report I recently developed.

```
'ws = worksheet object

 ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, _
Chr("Char Value of the column you wish to append your formula too")) _
.End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0).Formula = "=SUM(your range)"
```

Obviously youre going to have to fill in the blanks but you could easily create your dynamic range either from excel worksheet functions or simple matjh from recordset.RecordCount method.

Comment: Thank you for the tip.  It helped me finish.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final working code based on your help.  Regarding SUBTOTAL, I did have to change the first parameter to 9 instead of 109.  What I do have a question about is why do I need to set the first offset to (1.0) and the rest as (0,0) to get them to be on the same row?

```
'add Totals
'Its really strange.  Note how the offset for the first one is Offset(1,0)  and the rest are (0,0)
'If I don't do that, the rest will be 1 row lower


xlSheet.Cells(xlSheet.Rows.Count, Chr(99)).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUBTOTAL(9, R2C:R[-1]C)"   'C
xlSheet.Cells(xlSheet.Rows.Count, Chr(100)).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUBTOTAL(9, R2C:R[-1]C)"  'D
xlSheet.Cells(xlSheet.Rows.Count, Chr(101)).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUBTOTAL(9,R2C:R[-1]C)"   'E
xlSheet.Cells(xlSheet.Rows.Count, Chr(102)).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUBTOTAL(9,R2C:R[-1]C)"   'F
xlSheet.Cells(xlSheet.Rows.Count, Chr(103)).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUBTOTAL(9,R2C:R[-1]C)"   'G
xlSheet.Cells(xlSheet.Rows.Count, Chr(104)).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUBTOTAL(9,R2C:R[-1]C)"   'H
xlSheet.Cells(xlSheet.Rows.Count, Chr(105)).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUBTOTAL(9,R2C:R[-1]C)"   'I
xlSheet.Cells(xlSheet.Rows.Count, Chr(107)).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUBTOTAL(9,R2C:R[-1]C)"   'K
```

Comment: Chr("Control") isnt correct. The Chr function is using numeric equivalents of characters, i.e. a,b,c,+,/,*.

Comment: So control might be your header but the column is most likely still labeled "a"

Comment: both Chr(99) or Chr(67) give me a run-time error of 1004 Application-defined or object-defined error.  Could the error be on this side:  .End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0).Formula = "=SUBTOTAL(109, [ALLOCATION])"

Comment: i'm not aware of the subtotal function so it might be due to differing object models. Why not just use the sum formula which we know is an excel function?

Comment: Because if the user filters the list, for several items in the list, the total doesn't change.  I could only get it to change, when I use SUBTOTAL.  It is the same since 2003. If you go to the bottom of a column that you wish to total and hold alt+ <equals> you will get SUBTOTAL(109, [Your column Name])